# I am trying to set environment variable in postman using the prerequest but it is displaying an error

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set environment variable using the code postman.environment.set('Username','User'); in postman using the pre-request script but it is displaying an error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set')" in the console. How can I resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pm.environment.set('username','user')
```

you should use `pm` instead of `postman`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).